# Xcode best audio practices

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, soundeffect

What is the best practice for creating an audio prompt within my app, which will append different portions of audio together to ask a question?

ex. "What is" + "foo"?
    "What is" + "bar"?

I have developed a "AudioQueue" object using audiotool box which uses AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() and it is working perfectly.  Is there anything wrong with playing this type of audio through the alert system.  If so what are my alternatives??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to use this is an Audio CAPTCHA I don't recommend it, since Audio has been hacked in the past.

http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/05/google-recaptcha-brought-to-its-knees/

However, for general use I don't see anything wrong with it, other than it being potentially annoying.

If you tell a little more about the circumstances, we could evaluate weather this is a reasonable implementation choice.

Comment: I am writing an application which will prompt the user to touch an object on the screen. Since the objects vary I want my audio to be dynamic. The question will be the same for every prompt except for one part... "touch the" + "square"..."touch the " + "circle"

my question is, is it bad practice to use system sound services for this purpose?

Comment: What you are speaking of seems like an educational game. I have seen people use core audio for game engine: http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2003/Aug/msg00201.html For your project it might be fun to learn OpenAL, not that you necessarily need it: http://www.edenwaith.com/products/pige/tutorials/openal.php